# Include a TextView and override the text

Tags: android, include, textview, overriding

I have a TextView I use as the headline of my menu page:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/menuTextView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Menu"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="25sp"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Now I need a TextView with the same color, size and style on every sub menu in my app. Instead of copy pasting the whole TextView to every layout and just change the text in each one I thought I'd make one layout with the TextView and include it in every sub menu view, only overriding the text.

My code looks like this:

/layout/menutextview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/menuTextView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/default"
  android:textColor="@color/white"
  android:textSize="25sp"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The includes in each layout xml file tries to override the text attribute:

```
<include layout="@layout/menutextview" android:text="@string/menu" />

<include layout="@layout/menutextview" android:text="@string/settings" />
```

But the default text is displayed everywhere. Anyone have an idéa of what the problem might be?

Regards,
Mattias

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Include cannot be used to "overrride" children properties. It doesn't know which type of layout you will include, it will only inflate it and add it to the current layout.

To dynamically change the text, you need to do it in code.

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTextView);
textView1.setText(R.string.menu);

final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingsTextView);
textView2.setText(R.string.settings);
```

Comment: this is the most simple and mainteinance-friendly solution you can use for this problem.

Comment: Is there no custom field where I can pass whatever I want from the xml to the code? Like this: <include layout="@layout/menutextview" android:custom="@string/menu" /> Then in the code I could go ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuTextView)).setText(getCustom());

Comment: I wanted the same like you, and according to the documentation, you can only override the layout (and id) attributes.

Comment: @STTLCU I don't agree. Applying styling stuff should be kept in XML as much as possible for many reasons, so the other answer suggesting styles is better.

Comment: That's true for sure @popovitsj just keep in mind that when this answer was published (and therefore my comment) android was much younger, and I suppose much different than it's now.

Comment: You are right but this explanation not make sense "It doesn't know which type of layout you will include" , because it looks like it cannot be done the way de op wants, but its just choice in Android SDK to not allow it. Sure they could allow it and implement, I think most of the developers tried to use it that way and found its not possible because includes just looks like more useful then they are.

Answer (score 15):

Try using styles and have the TextView implement that style. This will make it easier to maintain consistency in your Views.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this with [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/). First you define a variable in your child layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
                name="buttonText"
                type="String" />
    </data>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{buttonText}"/>
</layout>
```

Then you set it in the other layout file where you include it:

```
<!-- .... other views -->
<include
    layout="@layout/inc_icon_button"
    bind:buttonText="@{`Put your String here`}" />
<!-- .... other views -->
```

Best case you would also have a variable in your parent layout to then just forward the binding.

Comment: Apparently I can't remove my upvote. What this answer is missing is: ++ root element of both parent and included layout has to be `<layout>`; ++ `<include>` can't be direct child of `<layout>` nor `<merge>`; ++ you have to use `DataBindingUtil.inflate` or `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` instead of plain `LayoutInflater.inflate` or `Activity.setContentView`. Otherwise it's helpful, but it took me quite some time to figure out why my code wasn't working.

Comment: Apparently I can't edit my comment anymore. In case that someone is wondering how to get the view from `DataBindingUtil.inflate`: `View rootView = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_layout, container, false).getRoot();`.

Comment: Note, for the "bind" attribute to be there, you need to include `xmlns:bind=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` inside of the layout tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following solution:

1. Give the include tag and the TextView in the include layout a specific id (like "section")
2. Declare the include tag as a view and a TextView in your code `View section;` and `TextView textview;`
3. Bind the View with the id of your include `section = findViewById(R.id.section);`
4. Bind the TextView of your include with `View.findViewById();`

`textview = section.findViewById(R.id.textview);`

I used the information from [**this**](https://mobikul.com/how-to-re-use-layouts-where-you-want-using/) side.