# Android: Better way to generate buttons

Tags: android

So far, my app is pretty simplistic and small. It has a few buttons here and there, but I can see it quickly getting out of hands with a ton of buttons. So my problem really, my activity_main.xml looks ridiculously ugly. It has a bunch of  tags, so I was wondering, what's the "correct" way to generate buttons when you have a lot of these?

Comment: If you want to separate your view from your logic, then XML is the way to go. If you move those buttons to code, you will now move the mess there.

Comment: @Voicu I see, so it appears that people agree in that regards. I'm just not very familiar as to what's considered standard vs bad practice in Android app development t.t Much to learn.

Comment: I don't have time to write out an example, but the use of a `styles.xml` in your values folder can greatly reduce the repetition in layouts and get around the limitations of incude. Include makes more sense when trying to reuse or compartmentalize a larger yet self-contained bit of layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things cleaner in your XML, you can use `include` to reference other XML which defines a generic button with all its common properties.

So the button would be defined under `genericbutton.xml` placed in the `layout` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

</merge>
```

And then your main `activity_main.xml` will have something like this for three buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        layout="@layout/genericbutton" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        layout="@layout/genericbutton" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        layout="@layout/genericbutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But in this case, you either set the same text for the buttons inside the `genericbutton.xml` or one by one in Java code. You cannot set it in the `include` tags.

Comment: Ah, damn, it would've been great if I could've set the button's text within the <include> :(

Comment: Oh yes. Here's a thread about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127013/include-a-textview-and-override-the-text

Comment: Thanks @Voicu I appreciate this. Let's see how far I can get with my app before I return to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

Use XML do define views. I would always recommend you to use xml, even if there are 20 Buttons.

Alternativly you can also set the button programmatically in code and at them to your layout. Just set the layout parameters and you are done.

Otherwise (if you have a list of many buttons and you need to scroll) a ListView or GridView would a good choice.

Comment: So I should make a new view and dump 20 buttons per view. (or how many buttons until it gets too messy). I'm just not very familiar what the standards are, and what's considered appropriate vs bad practice.